# SQL Order By using multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I have tried to look up for an answer here and outside, but can't seem to find a clear answer.

If we have this statement #1:

```
Select <columns> 
From <Table> 
Order By Column1 Desc, Column2 Desc
```

And this statement #2

```
Select <columns> 
From <Table> 
Order By Column1, Column2 Desc
```

In my opinion when you use #2, SQL sorts by `Column1` in an **ascending** order and then by `Column2` in **descending** order, while #1 sorts by both columns in a **descending** way. Am I correct?

I tried both in a query and the result was completely different, and fits my opinion... but I might still be wrong.

It's a long story but I don't understand why my app is generating the statement #1 instead of #2; it may be a platform bug which I need to report.

Comment: This is correct. `ASC` is implicit in an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

The #2 way is the same as 'Order by Field1 **asc**, Field2 **Desc**'

Please note that it will order by Field1 before Field2.